# google script to keep a running total when updated

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm designing a Google sheet to track stats for members of my gaming guild.  Stats will be updated often for each member and a running total must be kept for each stat of each member.

Example:  if Stat1 is updated then Stat1Total will equal Stat1Total + Stat1.

This needs to happen for multiple stats and the stats will not be updated at the same time.  Sometimes Stat1 for member 1 may be updated but not Stat2 and no stats for member 2.

I've tried Stat1Total=Stat1Total+Stat1 with Iterative calculation on but this updates all Stat Totals even if the Stat has not been updated.  I need the StatTotal to update only if the Stat has be updated.

I found this script, but can not work out how to adapt it to work on multiple/different cells.  This only works with B7 and B6 of a certain sheet. Maybe if it would get the active cell and then update a another cell based on what the active cell is?

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var b7 = s.getRange("B7");
  var b6 = s.getRange("B6");
  var activeCell = s.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  if( s.getName()=="Sheet1" && activeCell=="B6" )
    b7.setValue(b7.getValue()+b6.getValue());
};
```

Thank you in advance for any insight/help.

Edit:  Thanks for all the answers, but, probably due to my own inexperience, I'm still having trouble making it work.  So I will back track to my original problem with example:

```
         INF      INF TOTAL    Gems      GEMS TOTAL
```

Character 1  (A1)       (B1)       (C1)        (D1)

Character 2  (A2)       (B2)       (C2)        (D2)

So, I put in 100 in A1, B1 should update with B1+A1 and now B1 should =100.  Nothing else should update.  Then sometime later, I put 200 in A1, B1 should update to 300 (B1(100)+A1(200).  Again, nothing else should change.  Should also work for Character 2 and gems.  Make sense? Note:The totals will be on another sheet, but even if they must stay on same sheet I can get them over.

Again, I tried B1=B1+A1 but B1 updates on any event causing B1 to update by the value in A1 even if A1 is not updated.

I was hoping for a function which could see what was updated.  Something like:

(this would be in formula bar of cell B2      =MyFunction(B1)     It sees that B1 has been updated and then updates cell by that value.

Again, thank you all for the help and I apologize for my inexperience :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the coordinates of the edited cell and calculate the coordinates of the cell you need to write to by inspecting the event object (e). Try this

```
function onEdit(e) {

var editRange = e.range;  // the edited range
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() //change to your sheet
                          .getSheets()[0];
var editRow = editRange.getRow(); // row of the edited cell
var editCol = editRange.getColumn(); //column of the edited cell

var targetCol = 3;  //column index for the target cell

if(editCol == 2) {  // check if the cell was in column 2(B)

var editValue = editRange.getValue();

if(editValue) { //check if the value is not empty string("") or 0

    var targetRange = sheet.getRange(editRow, targetCol); //target cell in the same row as the edited cell
    targetRange.setValue(targetRange.getValue() + editValue);


}



}

}
```

Comment: The code above does exactly what you requested. It checks which cell was edited and makes changes only to the cell in the adjacent column.

Comment: Ahhh...now I see it.  I was getting wrapped around the total being in another sheet not the adjacent column. It will be easy to copy the total to another sheet.   Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I modified it just a bit by using e.range and added a few temp variables to debug it and it's working okay like this.  Make sure you create your onEdit event. And if you set notificaton to immediate you'll get feedback within a few minutes of problems in the event. BTW you don't have to name the function onEdit you can give it any valid function name.

```
function onEdit1(e) 
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var b7 = s.getRange("B7");
  var b6 = s.getRange("B6");
  //var activeCell = s.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  var editCell = e.range.getA1Notation();
  //var editCell='B6';
  if( s.getName()=="Sheet6" && editCell=="B6" )
  {
    var v = b7.getValue()+b6.getValue();
    //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('v = ' + v + ' editCell = ' + editCell);
    b7.setValue(v);
   }
}
```

Okay here's the code for the second example.

```
function onEdit1(e) 
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  if(col==1 && row<3)
  {
    s.getRange(row, col+1).setValue(Number(s.getRange(row, col+1).getValue())+Number(e.value));
  }
}
```

Comment: @Anton Dementiev I update and simplified the code for your second example.  If you want to add more rows the just change the `row<3` to a greater number.  Take a look at the [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) and don't forget to setup your onEdit() event.